# Why does "no sé" mean "I don't know?"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, definiciones

If "no" means "no", and if "se" means "is", why does "no sé" mean "I don't know"?

This has been a bit of stumbling block for me as I learn the language. I as learn how to learn, I like to know the literal and the why, and I can't get my brain around why "no se" means what it does.

Comment: What do you mean with *if "se" means "is"*...?

Comment: @rynomax Welcome to Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, spelling error questions are not really the kinds of questions we seek on this site. We're glad you got an answer, but I'm going to go ahead and close this question.

Comment: I don't think this is a spelling error question, but I think that this is definitely [too simple](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).

Comment: @Richard: It looks to me like a spelling error, because while "se" does not mean "is", "es" does... But at any rate, it is _some class of error_, and not a good question. :)

Answer (score 10):

The reason is because "**sé**" is the present conjugation of the verb "**saber**" for the pronoun "**Yo**", and "no" is the way to negate a verb in spanish. Therefore "no sé" (Yo no sé.) is "I don't know".

The conjugation depends of the pronoun. It is very common to ommit the subject.
For example:

> No sabemos. (Nosotro no sabemos)
>
> No sabe (El no sabe)
>
> Se que tengo que ir mañana al trabajo (Yo se...).

Check the conjugation of the verb "[saber](http://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/saber)".

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful.

Could you use the other present tense versions of **saber** instead of **sé**?

Comment: Yes, you could say, "El hombre no sabe," to say, "The man does not know."